# How do I have a keyboard entry start in a specific TextBox?

Tags: wpf

I have tried this:

```
<TextBox TabIndex="0" x:Name="gTBxt" GotKeyboardFocus="gTBxFirst_GotKeyboardFocus" />
```

plus:

```
private void gTBxFirst_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
    txtBox.SelectAll();
}
```

When the dialog box opens, keyboard entries are ignored (vs. appearing in this TextBox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viorel_ has a simple solution:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    gTBxt.Focus( );
    gTBxt.SelectAll( );
}
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/920c3941-f8c3-41b7-acc7-ec53875f223a/how-do-i-have-a-keyboard-entry-start-in-a-specific-textbox?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1):

On your Window-Tag you can add this

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=gTBxt}"
```

Hope this is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`FocusManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.focusmanager?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) and set it on the parent focus scope element to move logical focus to the `TextBox` (or any other `IInputElement`).

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="FocusScope" 
            FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=ActiveTextBox}">
  <TextBox />
  <TextBox x:Name="ActiveTextBox" Text="Active" />
  <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

**C#**

```
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this.FocusScope, this.ActiveTextBox);
```